# Android sqlite numeric filter

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, alphanumeric

I have table named "lantable" in sqlite database where there is a column named "engword". I want to filter those rows which does not starts with alphabets (i.e. starts with number or spl. charecters). How can I write the query in sqlite for android, so that I can fetch the data whose starts with alphabets. Is regular expression is solution for it? If it is how to use it in android-sqllite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *,lower(engword) as letter FROM tantable WHERE letter >= 'a' AND letter < '{';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL 'like' conditions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM lantable WHERE engword like '[0-9]%';
```

The above will give you all rows whose engword starts with 0 to 9 only.

Comment: Or you could also use the regexp for complex cases like this:  'SELECT * FROM lantable WHERE engword REGEXP <your_regex>'